# IDataErrorInfo based validation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, idataerrorinfo

**Edit**: This is a simplified update of the original version of this post.

In WPF I implemented a *UserControl* (called 'NumericTextBox') which uses a *DependencyProperty 'Value' that is kept in sync with the *Text* property of a *TextBox* (xaml):

```
<TextBox.Text>
  <Binding Path="Value" 
           Mode="TwoWay"
           ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
           NotifyOnValidationError="True"
           UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</TextBox.Text>
```

For validation purposes I use the *IDataErrorInfo* interface (xaml.cs):

```
public partial class NumericTextbox : Textbox, IDataErrorInfo {
    public double Value {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double),  
                                    typeof(NumericTextBox), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        // Never gets called!
        get { /* Some validation rules here */ }
    }
}
```

As stated in the source code, the `get` property actually **never gets called**, hence **no validation** happens. Do you see the reason for the problem?

**Edit2**: Based on ethicallogics' answer I restructered my code. The *NumericTextBox* now uses an underlying viewmodel class which provides a Dependency Property *Value* that is bound to the *Text* property of the *TextBox* which is declared by *NumericTextBox*. Additionally *NumericTextBox* uses the viewmodel as its datacontext. The viewmodel is now responsible for checking changes of the Value property. As the value restrictions of *NumericTextBox* are customizable (e.g. the Minimum can be adapted) it forwards these settings to the viewmodel object.

Comment: What exacly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, just updated the post.

Comment: So you want to check if user write a numbers only? Am I good understand your issue?

Comment: That and some additional conditions...

Comment: Hi Why you want that Property to be dependency property only. Why can't you apply Validation to ViewModel Property that is bind to the Text property of your TextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this rather than creating any Dependency Property . Validations are applied at ViewModel not in Control or View . Try it like this I hope this will help.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Value = 30;
    }
    private double _value;

    [Range(1, 80, ErrorMessage = "out of range")]
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            ValidationMessageSetter("Value", value);
        }
    }

    private void ValidationMessageSetter(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        Notify(propertyName);
        string validationresult = ValidateProperty(propertyName, value);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationresult) && !_dataErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            _dataErrors.Add(propertyName, validationresult);
        else if (_dataErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                _dataErrors.Remove(propertyName);

    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private void Notify(string str)
    { 
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str));
    }

    private string ValidateProperty(string propertyName,object value)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>(2);
        string error = string.Empty;

        bool result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
            value,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
            {
                MemberName = propertyName
            },
            results);

        if (!result && (value == null || ((value is int || value is long) && (int)value == 0) || (value is decimal && (decimal)value == 0)))
            return null;

        if (!result)
        {
            ValidationResult validationResult = results.First();
            error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }

        return error;    
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    private Dictionary<string, string> _dataErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataErrors.ContainsKey(columnName))
                return _dataErrors[columnName];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I just simplified the code. Now I use an approach that was inspired by your post and which is described in many tutorials (but nevertheless still fails in my program). Any further hints?

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer above . This works fine I hope this will help you to give an idea.

Comment: Thank you for this approach. It helped me develop a solution that works (see the first post). Actually it's still possible to use a dependency property. I do this for two reasons: 1. Using T4 Templates the amount of code can be greatly diminished. 2. It should be more performant as stated in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62158/DependencyProperties-or-INotifyPropertyChanged).

Answer (score 0):

The `IDataErrorInfo` interface should be implemented on the object that is being bound **to**, not on the object that has the `DependencyProperty`.

In your example, if you want to get validation using this mechanism then your view model needs to do something like the below for the `Value` property:

```
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        // Never gets called!
        get
        { 
            if (columnName == "Value")
                return GetValidationMessageForValueField();

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that what you actually want to do is to validate when someone enters a non-numeric value in the `TextBox`..?  If this is the case the you probably want to take a different approach than using `IDataErrorInfo`

Comment: Well i just did, what other tutorials also did (except that my property is actually a dependency property). E.g. have a look at  http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/

Comment: The difference is that in that tutorial the `Customer` class is the view model.  In your example, you are creating a `Control` (as you inherit from `TextBox`)

Comment: Ok, as I am totally unaware of what a viewmodel actually is and how to work with one, I will try to use another approach: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18678/Attaching-a-Virtual-Branch-to-the-Logical-Tree-in?msg=4321473#xx4321473xx

Comment: Ok.  Out of interest, what behaviour are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to have a textbox that is used for numeric input. So I want to accept only numbers as input. Therefore the user shall be warned if the input is either not a valid number, exceeds some boundaries (< or > a specific threshold) or if it is not a multiple of some predefined value (thus limiting the number of decimal places for instance). This textbox will then be combined with a slider.

Comment: To save you writing it yourself, why not try the Extended WPF toolkit control: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DoubleUpDown&referringTitle=NumericUpDown

Comment: The control seems very promising. Unfortunately I cannot use .NET 4.0 (just 3.5) and want to have a slider, no arrows. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can get a .NET 3.5 version of the toolkit on the downloads page (https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/84227) and you could easily replace the arrows with a slider by re-templating the control (or just hiding the arrows and binding a slider separately)